# Past Simple or Past Perfect? Why do we use them this way in the quote?

Tags: difference, past-tense, perfect-constructions

Here is a quote from "To Kill a Mockingbird":

> When enough years had gone by to enable us to look back on them, we
> sometimes discussed the events leading to his accident. I maintain
> that the Ewells started it all, but Jem, who was four years my senior,
> said it started long before that. He said it began the summer Dill
> came to us, when Dill first gave us the idea of making Boo Radley come
> out.

Why do we use only past simple here (except the first verb form)? It seems to me there should be Past Perfect at least several times in that text.

Comment: I agree. And is it really "I maintain", not "I maintained"? "I maintain" yet "Jem **said**"? It suggests the author is pretty relaxed about tenses.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - Presumably the narrator (Scout) still thinks the Ewells started it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. I suppose so, yes. Like "I maintained - and still do - that the Ewells . . ." I do think it sounds a bit awkward though, coming where it does.

Comment: Actually, the use of pluperfect would render the sentences clunky. It's perfect the way it's written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple reasons Harper Lee may have chosen to use simple past here.

One is that it's not strictly necessary. There's no meaning lost, nor unintelligible phrases, nor even anything difficult to parse.

Another is that she may have been writing in the vernacular of that time and place. She was writing a fictional story, but it was really about her home town, and it's possible the people in that town, at that time, used past perfect less often than is standard now.

Comment: Yes. Good points.